# How to define a method by making the "out" variable changeable in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, double, tryparse

These codes below work. But they are lengthy, so I wanted to create a method (lots of other TryParsing to do, this is just a small section).

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool resSPos = double.TryParse(txtSPos.Text, out double SPos);
    if (resSPos == false) FalseBoolMsg("Starting Position");

    bool resTPos = double.TryParse(txtTPos.Text, out double TPos);
    if (resTPos == false) FalseBoolMsg("Target Position");

    bool resIncr = double.TryParse(txtIncr.Text, out double Increment);
    if (resIncr == false) FalseBoolMsg("Increment");

    Ch.FunctionA(Ch.FunctionX, SomeInt, Increment, Ch.FunctionY);
    Ch.FunctionB(SomeInt, SPos, Ch.FunctionY);
    Ch.FunctionA(0, SomeInt, TPos, Ch.FunctionZ);             

}
```

"FalseBoolMsg" is just a method I defined higher-up for generating a MessageBox. "txtSPos", "txtTPos" and "txtIncr" are just TextBoxes in my Windows Form. Anyway, below is what I attempted but failed. I've tried several variations but to no avail. Mainly, I have a problem with the 'double' parameter more so than the string ones.

```
private void TryParseDouble(string ParseTarget, string PointField, string FieldInMsg)
{
    bool resBool = double.TryParse(ParseTarget, out double PointField);
    if (resBool == false) FalseBoolMsg(FieldInMsg);
}
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TryParseDouble("txtSPos.Text", "SPos", "Starting Position");

    TryParseDouble("txtTPos.Text", "TPos", "Target Position");

    TryParseDouble("txtIncr.Text", "Increment", "Increment");

    Ch.FunctionA(Ch.FunctionX, SomeInt, Increment, Ch.FunctionY);
    Ch.FunctionB(SomeInt, SPos, Ch.FunctionY);
    Ch.FunctionA(0, SomeInt, TPos, Ch.FunctionZ);             

}
```

Yes, I can change "string PointField" to "double PointField" in my method but that means I must key in an actual number when I recall the method, instead of typing in the name to replace "PointField". I also need the functions to read the "double Name" produced by the TryParse from my method. Thank you for your consideration.

Edit: I've found the answer thanks to John ([What is the proper method or keyword to put in a user-defined method that renames a variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402927/what-is-the-proper-method-or-keyword-to-put-in-a-user-defined-method-that-rename))

```
private bool TryParseDouble(string ParseTarget, out double PointField, string FieldInMsg)
{
    if (!double.TryParse(ParseTarget, out PointField))
    {
        FalseBoolMsg(FieldInMsg);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TryParseDouble(txtSPos.Text, out double SPos, "Starting Position");
}
```

Comment: I assume `SPos` `TPos` and `Increment` are properties of the same class?

Comment: BTW `"txtSPos.Text"` should be `txtSPos.Text`

Comment: What problem you have with the double parameter. I'm afraid it's not clear at all. I also don't understand: _"I must key in an actual number when I recall the method"_

Comment: I think he is using an autoproperty, which is why he can't pass it as out

Comment: Hi Sebastian, if you see the working code, SPos, TPos and Increment are just names I gave for the "out doubles". I can name them anything I like in the "out double" as long as I recall the same names in the functions.

Hi Rahul, thanks for the tip but I still can't figure out a method to make all this work.

Comment: @Stoverflow: Why `TryParseDouble` has not this signature: `private void TryParseDouble(string parseText, out double parsedDouble, string falseMessage)`?

Comment: Hi Tim. If I use "double PointField" instead of "string PointField" I'll have to recall the method like this for example:

        { TryParseDouble(txtSPos.Text, 42, "Starting Position") }

where 42 is a random number. I want it to be "SPos" in this case.

Comment: Hi Tim, if I use

private void TryParseDouble(string parseText, out double parsedDouble, string falseMessage)

I get error squiggly line on the TryParseDouble.

Answer (score 0):

Though not entirely clear but I think you want to replace the out variable name in your `TryParse()` method per the argument supplied in method. In that case, you can use a `switch` statement like below. Though, don't see any reason for doing that

```
private void TryParseDouble(string ParseTarget, string PointField, string FieldInMsg)
{
 bool resBool; 
  switch (PointField)
  {
      case "SPos":
          resBool = double.TryParse(ParseTarget, out double SPos);
          break;
      case "TPos":
          resBool = double.TryParse(ParseTarget, out double TPos);
          break;
      case "Increment":
          resBool = double.TryParse(ParseTarget, out double Increment);
          break;
      default:              
          break;
  }

    if (!resBool) FalseBoolMsg(FieldInMsg);
}
```

You should call it like

```
TryParseDouble(txtTPos.Text, "TPos", "Target Position");
```

Comment: Why not passing the double as out parameter into this method? Then you also get the value which was parsed. I don't understand this question though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's more of an guessed answer and so said in post clearly.

Comment: What is the benefit of this method? It just allows to make mistakes and doesn't give anything useful back. Sure, the `FalseBoolMsg` call, but that could be achieved easier with a `out double` parameter.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the suggestion. I think it will work but other than "SPos", "TPos" and "Increment" I have many other "double" variables I need to name besides those three, meaning I'll have to add many cases.

Comment: @Stoverflow, in that case would suggest you to rethink your design once cause what you are saying doesn't looks correct